# How to get EPSG:4326 coordinates on Drag and drop in OpenLayers

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, drag-and-drop

I followed the [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-custom-mvt.html) on how to implement a drag and drop interaction with openLayers.

I now want to read the coordinate of every features like the following

```
this.dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', (event: DragAndDropEvent) => {
      const features: Feature<Geometry>[] = event.features

      features.forEach((feature, index) => {
        const properties = feature.getProperties()
        const coordinates = properties?.geometry

        console.log(coordinates.flatCoordinates)
      })
    })
```

But I get `[799785.5152789096,...]` and I wanted to have it with the EPSG:4326 format.

I did try to change the projections when I initialized the map like this

```
 const dragAndDropInteraction = new DragAndDrop({
    formatConstructors: [<any>GPX, KML],
    projections: 'EPSG:4326',
  })

this.map = new Map({
  projections: 'EPSG:4326',
  interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([this.dragAndDropInteraction]),
  target: target,
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
  ],
  view: this.view,
})
```

But I keep get the wrong coordinate.

Is it normal?

I'm importing a KML file
Here is his content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
  xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <Document>
    <name>Traces du passé</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="default0">
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="default">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#default0</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#hl</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="hl">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.2</scale>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder id="kml_ft_Sentier">
      <name>Sentier</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>31</name>
        <description>La porte de Fully</description>
        <LookAt>
          <longitude>7.184550738826426</longitude>
          <latitude>46.17214547339596</latitude>
          <altitude>0</altitude>
          <heading>-0.0005252280984056049</heading>
          <tilt>60.00131024332176</tilt>
          <range>168.3472321103629</range>
          <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#default</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
          <coordinates>7.184330180845047,46.17181721801122,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
    </Document>
  </kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features are displayed in the view projection, to get the EPSG:4326 coordinates the geometry must be cloned and transformed back to EPSG:4326

```
  features.forEach((feature, index) => {
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry().clone().transform(map.getView().getProjection(), 'EPSG:4326');

    console.log(geometry)
  })
})
```

Comment: Well, it did work. I understand that it take the default view projection, but why does it didn't had the right projection from the beginning ?

Comment: If your view uses meters as projection units and the feature was in EPSG:4326 the feature would appear very small near point [0, 0] in the projection.